# what should the frame_id of topic "poseX" be, before use robot_localization package?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello:

According to `r_l`(robot_localization) wiki, [coordinate-frames-and-transforming-sensor-data doc](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html?#coordinate-frames-and-transforming-sensor-data), it can transforms `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped,` on topic "poseX",  in message header’s frame_id into the coordinate frame specified by the world_frame parameter (typically map or odom). I think this topic probably can be provided by a stereo VO, because mono VO cannot provide real scale info.

when i see the ["poseX" callback function](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1135), it then calls [preparePose func](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2481), in this line [RosFilterUtilities::lookupTransformSafe()](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2570), it lookuptransform from "finalTargetFrame"(if we set it as odom), to pose msg.frame_id, **what should this frame_id on this topic be?**  It looks like `r_l` thinks this frame is odom, the transform msg work should be done by users before use `r_l`, just like [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros)?

Generally speaking, the frame_id of pose on this topic is a fixed frame, such as a camera_0 frame(in some moment, camea is launched by its driver ros node).  Only when we know what time stamp of camera is launched, we can get from odom frame to this camera_0 frame from tf tree, let we mark this as `T_odom_to_camera0`, and then we can transform msg on topic poseX to odom frame, `T_odom_to_camera = T_odom_to_camera0 *  T(msg_on_poseX)`, `T_odom_to_baselink = T_odom_to_camera  * T_camera_to_baselink`., which  `T_odom_to_baselink` is from odom frame to baselink with camera pictures estimated, `T_camera_to_baselink` is a tf static transform.

In other words, if robot base node and camera driver node are launched on the same time from start, `T_odom_to_camera0` equals to `T_baselink_to_camera` ,we can get this TF directlly from tf tree. If they does not launched on the same time, we need to record time stamp of camera launched, because we need to record `T_odom_to_camera0`, anything wrong??

Currentlly, my idea is:

1: If we set world_frame is map,  r_l thinks the default meaning of pose on topic poseX is base_link frame in map frame. The reason is : if the pose on topic poseX is base_link in odom, although with odom topic, we have no sources measuring base_link in map, r_l can not calculate a TF from map--->odom.

2: If we set world_frame is odom, r_l thinks the default meaning of pose on topic poseX is base_link frame in odom frame. r_l publishs a TF from odom--->base_link.

Regardless of which above case, when the poseX topic is provided by camera VO, the transform work including recording the TF between camera0 pose and odom(map), should be done by user before using r_l.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302131/what-should-the-frame_id-of-topic-%22posex%22-be,-before-use-robot_localization-package?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2018-08-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-02**:
I don't understand what "poseX" is supposed to be

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2018-09-03**:
"poseX" is pose0, pose1,..., posen topic of type `geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped` , defined in [pose topic callback](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1134)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think specifying `frame_id` of the pose message published by `camera_node` to say `camera_link` and providing a static transform `camera_link -> base_link` should be sufficient (assuming you have set `base_link_frame` parameter to `base_link` and both `world_frame` and `odom_frame` to `odom`) if you only want fuse the camera pose data with some other sensor to generate an odometry.

If the robot already publishes an odometry (i.e. the transform `odom -> base_link` is already available through other means), setting `world_frame` to `map` would allow to fuse the pose to generate a global pose with respect to this `world_frame`

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2018-09-05**:
I don't agree that we should  set frame_id of poseX as camera or camera_link, because `geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped` type's header frame id is a global frame, such as `nav_msgs::Odometry` 's pose component.

**Comment by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) on 2018-09-05**:
Ah yes, you are correct. My mistake! I

What I meant to say was to set `frame_id` to use the fixed frame id as you have suggested (to use `camera0_frame`) and providing a static transform between `camera0_frame -> odom`.

**Comment by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) on 2018-09-05**:
If you know that `base_link` starts at `odom` frame's origin each time, then `camera0_frame -> odom` is identical to the `camera_link -> base_link` transformation. Otherwise, you'd have to compute `camera0_frame -> odom = base_link -> odom * camera_link -> base_link` once at the start of pose node

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2018-09-05**:
Agree with you ^-^